# How to Accept an Answer in Stackexchange

Tags: discussion, answers

Hi I'm new to this site and need some help with how it works. How do I accept an answer given to a question I asked.

Comment: I don't seem to have that sort of arrows or checkmarks next to the answer to my question. Is it because I'm new and there's some sort of probationary period before I can fully participate.

Comment: You'll find your answer here: [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) There's a brief period ([15 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50697/168244)) immediately after asking the question when you can't accept an answer.

Comment: Oh all right. Thanks for the answer!